# MySQL BETWEEN clause with Yii PHP framework

Tags: php, mysql, yii, between

Using Yii PHP framework, I produce the following query

```
SELECT * FROM `purchases` WHERE (date BETWEEN '2013-12-31' AND '2015-01-01')
```

with this code

```
$exportYear = "2014";
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addBetweenCondition("date", ((int)$exportYear - 1) . "-12-31", ((int)$exportYear + 1) . "-01-01");
$purchases = Purchase::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

What I actually need is all 'purchases' that happened in year 2014. None from a minute before or after. What does the addBetweenCondition line need to be changed to in order to accomplish this?

Comment: why not just `where year(date) = 2014`?

Comment: @MarcB: That can't make use of indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BETWEEN operator is inclusive.

If column type is DATE use **'2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31'**

```
$exportYear = "2014";
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addBetweenCondition("date", $exportYear . "-01-01", $exportYear . "-12-31");
$purchases = Purchase::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

If column type is DATETIME use **'2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-12-31 23:59:59'**

```
$exportYear = "2014";
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addBetweenCondition("date", $exportYear . "-01-01 00:00:00", $exportYear . "-12-31 23:59:59");
$purchases = Purchase::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `purchases` 
WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31'
```